# Fixed position doesn't pop Image out of div

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I've have problem with showing images on my project. I would like to show image when I hover text. It's working correctly if using Chrome but at least in Safari image stays partly hidden inside it's parent element.

[image]
[Screenshot from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG3Ta.jpg)

[image]
[Screenshot from Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpdYr.jpg)

Code for parent element:

```
const PortfolioItemsWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
`
```

```
<PortfolioItemsWrapper>
 {props.allWordpressWpPortfolio.edges.map(portfolioItem => (
  <PortfolioWorks
   key={portfolioItem.node.id}
   image={portfolioItem.node.featured_media.source_url}
   id={portfolioItem.node.id}
   title={portfolioItem.node.title}
   link={`/portfolio/${portfolioItem.node.slug}`}
  />
 ))}
</PortfolioItemsWrapper>
```

Code for image:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
`

const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
`

const PortfolioImage = styled.img`
  max-width: 300px;
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s linear;
`
```

```
    <Wrapper key={id}>

      <ImageWrapper>
        <PortfolioImage style={imageStyle} src={image} />
      </ImageWrapper>

      <PortfolioItemNameLink to={link} onMouseEnter={changeStyle} onMouseLeave={resetStyle}>
        {title}
      </PortfolioItemNameLink>
    </Wrapper>
```

Comment: You have a negative z-index for the image. You'll probably either need to update that on hover or remove it altogether.

Comment: I Just figured if I took  ```overflow-x: scroll;``` away from parent element images are showing correctly but then the titles are not setting as I want...

Comment: I tried to change z-index value to 9999 with no effect so I removed it entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this right by just pretty randomly testing things. Don't know why but it's working. If someone knows why I would like to know.

I set fixed position for parent div of `PortfolioItemsWrapper`.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
`

const PortfolioItemsWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure this might work:

Try adding `overflow-y: visible;` to your parents css.

Let me know if that works :)

Comment: I tried this and it's not solution for this problem.